# VSCode: Searching into all project content

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since VSCode version 1.31 I can't find anything into my project files. I've already reinstalled the VSCode App on my Mac, but nothing happened on it.

This option doesn't work without open the files before:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files

I've been searching on the web, but I didn't find anyone with the same problem as me.

Please, help me!!

Comment: Make sure all your individual files are in a single folder. And open that folder entirely and perform the search.

Comment: The problem has been solved. You need to change the way that you open your projects files. Open the project files in 'Open workspace' button. If it doesn't allow the button to open your projects, select the option 'Add Folder to Workspace...' and select your main project path. After that, the searched files and the git changes will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make all your files visible in search you must always make sure all the necessary files are present in the same director. And then as Renee stated in the comments above, you should add your working folder to the Workspace or open folder from the start screen. Below are the screen snippets of the Visual Studio code's start screen from where you can file `Add Workspace Folder` button. If it is not found, you can always find it under `File` menu.

[image]
[image]